# Coldfusion and Brightcove API

Tags: api, coldfusion, brightcove

Does anybody have any idea how to use CFHTTP with the BrightCove API?

I just want to get a count of my videos. I am able to successfully get my access token (VARIABLES.access_token) from the BrightCove API but I keep getting permission denied message.

Here's the code that I've been trying to get working:

```
<CFHTTP url="https://cms.api.brightcove.com/v1/accounts/:#VARIABLES.acctid#/counts/videos" method="get">
    <CFHTTPPARAM type="header" name="Content-type" value="Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
    <CFHTTPPARAM type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer {#VARIABLES.access_token#}"/>
```

Comment: cfhttp returns a bunch of variables. Have you tried `<cfdump>`ing them?

Comment: Are you sure you want these colons `:` before the account ID? The docs use them as placeholders as far as I can tell. Examples show digits only.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working finally.  It was just a stupid syntax error like it almost always is.  I had to add more details to the value attribute for both cfhttpparams.  I also had an error in my original url path above. I put a ":" which was wrong.  The syntax below has a different URL value which I got working as well.

```
<CFHTTP url="https://cms.api.brightcove.com/v1/accounts/#VARIABLES.acctid#/videos/xxxxxxx" method="get" charset="utf-8" throwonerror="yes">
<CFHTTPPARAM type="header" name="Content-type" value="Content-type:application/json"/>
<CFHTTPPARAM type="header" name="Authorization" value="Authorization: Bearer #VARIABLES.access_token#"/>
</CFHTTP>
```